# MySQL Returns to null and couple other problems

Tags: mysql

Okay guys, i need to find List all of the months that movies were released in.  and i need to show for each month how many movies were released. So i need two columns one for month and one for number of movies.

So my code is like this

```
SELECT monthname(ReleaseDate) AS 'MONTHS', COUNT(*)
FROM Mymovies
```

but it's just showing me september. What should i do? Here's my values

```
(
MovieName VARCHAR(20),
ReleaseDate DATE,
Cost INT (10),
Revenue INT (10) 
);
```

Comment: Where does `Revenue-Cost` column exist?

Comment: @CynePhoba12 That's not a column name, it's a subtraction.

Comment: Don't put multiple problems in the same question. Each problem should be a separate question.

Comment: Your first query looks fine. It will only return `NULL` if `Cost` is `0`, because you can't divide by zero.

Comment: You need `GROUP BY MovieName` in the first query to get the maximum profit for each movie.

Comment: @Balmar, my cost is not 0 though. Can it do it because i use $ and M's on my cost?

Comment: All these columns should be numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query you need `GROUP BY` so you'll get the results for each movie name.

```
SELECT MovieName,
MAX((Revenue-Cost)/Cost) AS 'RETURNS'
FROM myMovies
GROUP BY MovieName
```

To get the total income, use `SUM(Revenue)`:

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue) AS TotalIncome
FROM myMOvies
WHERE ReleaseDate BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1999-12-31'
```

The `Revenue` and `Cost` columns should be numeric, either `INT` or `DECIMAL` types, not strings. They shouldn't include characters like `$`, because MySQL can't perform arithmetic when numbers have extraneous characters like that.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your queries are close, but slightly invalid. Let's start with query one:

```
SELECT MovieName,
MAX((Revenue-Cost)/Cost) AS 'RETURNS'
FROM myMovies;
```

Then problem is that `Revenue-Cost` is evaluated as a column **literally** called `Revenue-Cost`. To do a subtraction, you need to include a space. You also need a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT MovieName,
MAX((Revenue - Cost)/Cost) AS 'RETURNS'
FROM myMovies GROUP BY MovieName
```

As for your second (modified) query:

```
SELECT ReleaseDate, MovieName
From myMovies WHERE,
ReleaseDate BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1999-12-31'
```

You will have an error, as you added an extra comma. To get the total revenue, it's just the sum of the revenue rows:

```
SELECT SUM(Revenue)
From myMovies WHERE
ReleaseDate BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '1999-12-31'
```

Hope this helps!